# Non-overlapping free-float frames

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames

The squared spacetime interval in two overlapping free-float frames is invariant. But how can two free-float frames not overlap?

Both frames will stretch over all of spacetime, so won't they always overlap?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be based on a passage in Ch 3.3 of Spacetime Physics v.2 by Taylor and Wheeler.

> Edwin F. Taylor & John Archibald Wheeler
>
> 3.7: Invariance of the Interval Proved
> laboratory and rocket observers agree on something important
> The Principle of Relativity has a major consequence. It demands that the spacetime interval have the same value as measured by observers in every overlapping free-float frame; in brief, it demands "invariance of the interval."

The "overlap" condition was mentioned in Ch 2.9

> Let rocket and laboratory latticeworks be overlapping in the sense that a region of spacetime exists common to both frames.

Mathematically, it seems like it is a physicist's reference to overlapping charts on a manifold.

Physically, in practical terms,
it seems to be saying that the two observers are "studying the same thing (same geometric object) with their instruments" and can form an invariant quantity based on their measurements.

In special relativity, there is an overlap.. but, in general relativity, that might not be so.